# Array de ponteiros que apontam Funções

Tags: c, array, funções, ponteiro

Boa tarde.

Gostaria de saber se o código abaixo está certo. Tenho um pouco de dificuldade em ponteiros e entrei nessa área de ponteiros pra funções e gostaria de entender mais sobre essa opção.

```
//Declarando o ARRAY de ponteiros que apontam funções
void (*funcoes[2])(void) = {&funcao1, &funcao2};
funcaoQueEnviaOArray(funcoes);

//Declarando a função que recebe o array
void funcaoQueRecebeArray(void (*arrayFuncoes[])(void)){
    //Chamando a função dentro do array
    arrayFuncoes[0]();
}
```